# Yii2 | GridView table, не срабатывает связть между моделями

Tags: php, yii2, relation

Код в контроллере

```
  public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new SuggestedNewsSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->getAllNews(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'searchModel' => $searchModel
        ]);
    }
```

Модель класса SuggestedNews

```
class SuggestedNews extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'suggested_news';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'Title',
            'news' => 'News',
            'category' => 'Category',
            'status' => 'Status',
            'date' => 'Date',
            'news_source' => 'News Source',
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['title'], 'string'],
            [['news'], 'string'],
            [['category'], 'integer'],
            [['status'], 'integer'],
            [['date'], 'datetime'],
            [['news_source'], 'string'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category']);
    }

    public function deleteNewsById($id)
    {
        $customer = $this::findOne($id);
        if ($customer->delete()) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

код модели SuggestedNewsSearch

```
class SuggestedNewsSearch extends SuggestedNews
{

    public function getAllNews($params)
    {
        $query = $this::find();

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        if ($this->validate() AND !($this->load($params))) {
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        if (!empty($this->getAttribute('title'))) {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'title', $this->getAttribute('title')]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->getAttribute('category'))) {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'category', $this->getAttribute('category')]);
        }
        if (!empty($this->getAttribute('status'))) {
            $query->andFilterWhere(['LIKE', 'status', $this->getAttribute('status')]);
        }

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

вывод таблицы

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'id',
        [
            'attribute' => 'title',
            'format' => 'text',
            'label' => 'title',
            'filter' => true,
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'category.Category',
            'format' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Category',
        ],
        [
            'attribute' => 'status',
            'filter' => true,
        ],
        'date',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
        ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

модель Category

```
class Category extends ActiveRecord
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'category';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name'], 'required'],
            [['name'], 'string'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Имя категории',
        ];
    }

    public function getSuggestedNews()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SuggestedNews::className(), ['category' => 'id']);
    }

    public function getCategory(){
        return $this->name;
    }

}
```

Таблица выводится и все хорошо, но почему то не выводиться данная в `'attribute' => 'category.Category'`, выводит постоянно `(not set)`

Таблицы связаны между собой при помощи FK
Таблица suggested_news
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таблица category
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если `category.category`? (всё строчными буквами) Или `category.name`

Comment: Делал, ничего не работает, я просто в тупике. Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: 'attribute' => 'category.name'

Answer (score 0):

У вас не работает, потому что поле в базе и функция

```
    public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'category']);
```

}

названы одинаково, вам надо поменять поле в базе на category_id или переименовать функцию, например getCategoryObj и тогда в grid обращаться к этому полю соответственно, если вы переименовали поле то category.category а если переименуете функцию, что проще на мой взгляд, то в grid обращаться categoryObj.category